# ffmpeg raw video and audio stdin

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg

Currently, I am using ffmpeg to start from frames in raw format to generate a video output that is broadcast in OBS.

The problem is that we want to add an audio track to it, that is: each frame will now have its matrix of pixels and its audio.

I don't know exactly how to make ffmpeg take this composite signal or what the best methodology is. Actually I use the stdin of the ffmpeg. I use this code to generate it:

```
url = "udp://" + udp_address + ":" + str(udp_port)
command = [
        'ffmpeg',
         '-loglevel',
         'error',
         '-re',
         '-y',
         
         # Input
         '-i', '-',
         '-f', 'rawvideo',
         '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
         '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
         '-s', str(size[0]) + 'x' + str(size[1]),
         
         # Output
         '-b:v', '16M',
         '-maxrate', '16M',
         '-bufsize', '16M',
         '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
         '-f', 'mpegts', url
 ]

proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

What would be the best methodology to add audio to each frame?
Thanks

Comment: The solution you are looking for might be in this [https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg](link)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) (FIFO). Simplified example for Linux/macOS:

1. Make named pipes:

   ```
   mkfifo video
   mkfifo audio
   ```
2. Output/pipe video and audio to stdout. This is using `ffmpeg` to generate video and audio to the named pipes just for demonstration purposes.

   ```
   ffmpeg -y -re -f lavfi -i testsrc2=s=1280x720:r=25 -f rawvideo video & ffmpeg -y -re -f lavfi -i sine=r=44100 -f s16le audio
   ```
3. Use the named pipes as inputs for `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f rawvideo -video_size 320x240 -pixel_format yuv420p -framerate 25 -i video -f s16le -sample_rate 44100 -channels 1 -i audio -t 10 output.mp4
   ```

Comment: How do you do it with dynamic frame rate

Comment: @bluejayke You mean variable frame rate (VFR)? Depends on what you want ffmpeg to do. But it's a completely different topic than the original question.

Answer (score 0):

With FFMPEG you can have multiple inputs and then use the -map flag to choose what input streams should be used.

For example if you have 1 video and 1 audio fragment you can use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Map can be used to select the different input streams. In this case:

- From the first input, from the video streams, take the first one (0:v:0)
- From the second input, from the audio streams, take the first one (1:a:0)

[image]

To find more information see: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map

-Devedse

Comment: How can this be used with with -cat operator for dynamic frame durations